# C++ New File Issue in Visual Studio Express 2015

Tags: c++, visual-studio, visual-c++, visual-studio-2015

I have a peculiar issue in Visual Studio Express 2015.  I am trying to create a new empty Win32 Console Application project in Visual C++.  I can create a new project, clear the check boxes for precompiled headers and SDL checks as well as check the box for "Empty Project".  The project is created, but when I go to add a new item to my source files, I have nothing to choose from under "Installed".  Under previous versions, I could choose a new blank C++ (.cpp) file or a Header (.h) file.  I can create new .vb files under Visual Basic and new .cs files under C#, but the "Add" button is grayed out when I try to create a new C++ file.  Anybody got any ideas?  I've installed this on three different computers with the same results (Windows 7 OS on all 3).  I've attached a screenshot of the Add new item dialog.

[image: screenshot]

Comment: BTW, typing a file name in the box does NOT enable the Add button.

Comment: C++ parts arent installed by default anymore, but without them, I guess you couldn't make a new project from the template. I was unable to repro your situation by fiddling with install options. I was able to repro your screenshot precisely by using the keyboard 'tab' to navigate through that dialog box. Microsoft is using homemade user interfaces for no good reason nowadays--is it possible you've installed some desktop theming software on each of these systems which is incompatible with this part of VS? I have problems with VS over teamviewer for some unfathomable reason.

Comment: Thanks for the response.  I actually just figured out how to fix my problem just a minute ago. I installed a trial version of Visual Studio 2015 enterprise on one of the computers in question after uninstalling VS Express 2015. The C++ files worked normally under that setup (I did do a custom installation and made sure to include all the C++ items).  I looked in the C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 14.0\VC folder and noticed that the vcprojectitems folder was named vcprojectitems_WDExpress on my other computer.  I copied that folder and renamed to vcprojectitems.  It works now.

Answer (score 13):

What worked for me was to copy all the files except the Utility directory from C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 14.0\VC\VCProjectItems_WDExpress 
into
C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 14.0\VC\vcprojectitems

When I added an item (Right click on Source Files directory in Visual Studio Express Solution Explorer), all the cpp items were available.

Comment: In case that folder does not exist, just create a new one. Worked for me, +1

Comment: you don't need to copy, just change the name of the folder from "VCProjectItems_WDExpress" into "VCProjectItems".

Answer (score 5):

I encountered this problem after downloading and installing Visual Studio Express 14.0 on April 16 2016. This seems to be the re-emergence of a problem encountered in earlier versions of Visual Studio Express. [This is a link](https://connect.microsoft.com/VisualStudio/feedback/details/800202/visual-studio-2013-express-rc-no-items-found-in-the-add-new-item-dialog) to a workaround for version 12.0, involving a straightforward edit to the registry:

> [HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\Microsoft\WDExpress\12.0_Config\Projects{8BC9CEB8-8B4A-11D0-8D11-00A0C91BC943}\AddItemTemplates\TemplateDirs{F1C25864-3097-11D2-A5C5-00C04F7968B4}/1]
>
> "TemplatesDir"="C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 12.0\\VC\VCProjectItems_WDExpress"

I followed the instructions except for altering the version number from 12.0 to 14.0 where relevant, and it solved the problem.

Possibly the problem arose because alongside the installation of Studio Express, it seems that a Microsoft Update updated the Microsoft Visual C++ Redistributable (x64) and (x86). The consequence was an error message at the end of the Studio Express installation, because the version number of these installed C++ components was higher than those included in the Studio Express download. Deinstalling the later versions and then rerunning the Studio Express installation was successful in so far as there was no error message, but this problem with New Item was there.

Comment: Thanks for your response.  After doing some experimenting, I have found that if you rename 
C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 14.0\VC\vcprojectitems_WDExpress 
to 
C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 14.0\VC\vcprojectitems
You can successfully create new .cpp and .h files like normal after you restart VSE2015.

Answer (score 1):

I did ALMOST the same as Mr. Hill

I copied the whole directory and renamed the copied directory to the second one. I found it wasn't even in the directory. I am Windows 10 Home Edition.  ... also trying to get back up to speed to the latest VC Studio and Windows, .... don't laugh but I'm very happy with V6.0 and Win XP, but I can't keep supporting Windows XP forever. See changes at the bottom of my post.

Btw all the apps that I make in V6.0 work in Windows 10: As Databases, I'm using my own database made from `fopen,fwrite, sqlite and Dao MSACCESS 97`.  There is one app that I have to port to MFC. It's not necessary that I upgrade to the Latest VStudio at the moment, But I'm going to be doing it. Can't live in the past forever,... well maybe lol?

Also, I don't like the new GUI features of WINDOWS 7 and WINDOWS 10. My recommendation to MICROSOFT is to make Windows 11 with a look and feel more like Windows XP(or at least a switch to give users that option) but of course they will be obligated to add new features to keep up with technology. I don't like all the pop-ups on rollovers and the new files control dialog.

..sorry for the types: These new PCs and WINDOWS 10 are very cumbersome with all the pop up that appears when you do rollovers.

Thanks to everyone on this thread, and special thanks to Mr. Hill

Chaneges to system:

> C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio
>   14.0\VC\VCProjectItems_WDExpress  into  C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 14.0\VC\VCProjectItems